# Live demo site reinstaller

Tags: php, mysql, demo

I have a live demo site for some purpose. Public visitors can login as admin and change what they want. I need to reinstall (refresh with first original data and files) **database** and **ftp** periodically (ex:per 1 hour)...

Do you guys know any open source script for this purpose? I do not want to code myself if it  available already...

thank you for everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a "solution" for this: this takes only a single line in a cron job: you use sqlite as database and then all you need to do is execute a simple `cp` command every hour.

Comment: thank you for answer. its not possibel to use sqlite. Mysql is database. But you give me idea to use cron job at least ftp replace. thank you...

Comment: Ok, if you really _must_ use mysql, then it is _two_ lines: `cp -pr ...` for the files and `mysql ...` to load the database from a previous dump.